# Ruby code efficiency

Tags: ruby, while-loop, do-while

Is there a way to make this code shorter and simpler?

```
loop do 
    if possibleSet.split(" ").map(&:to_i).any? {|e| (e<0 || e>12)}
        print "Please enter valid numbers (between 1 and 12): "
        possibleSet = gets
        errorinput = false
    else
        errorinput = true
    end
    break if errorinput
end
```

Comment: This looks like you could use the until keyword

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refactored a bit :)

```
loop do 
    print "Please enter valid numbers (between 1 and 12): "
    possibleSet = gets.chomp
    break unless possibleSet.split(" ").map(&:to_i).any? {|e| (e<0 || e>12)}
   end
```

Comment: `possibleSet` is buried inside `loop`, making this code unusable.

Comment: it really is @mudasobwa... I just refactored his code as he wished, leaving the original logic intact

Answer (score 1):

The code below will check input for correctness:

```
input = loop do
  print "Please enter valid numbers (between 1 and 12): "
                          # ⇓⇓⇓ as many spaces as user wants
  input = gets.chomp.split(/\s+/).map(&:to_i) rescue []
  break input unless input.empty? || input.any? { |i| !(0..12).include? i }
end
```

Comment: The range `include?` call does make this cleaner. Switching to `input.none?` would remove the need for negation.

Comment: @tadman `input.none?` always performs N iterations, while `input.any?` might return on the first one. Premature optimization :)

Answer (score 0):

This parses the user input in an array (not exactly the same behavior, but I hope it is cleaner and you can work from there)

```
set = []
until set.all? {|i| (1..11).include?(i) } && !set.empty? do
  set = gets.split(' ').map(&:to_i)
end
```

Comment: sorry 'bout that, added a check for set.empty?